# How to extend MUI 5 theme with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to extend MUI 5 theme with TypeScript module augmentation but getting error

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'status' does
> not exist in type 'ThemeOptions'.

It looks like TS doesn't know about existing types declaration in theme.d.ts. How to fix that?

**src/theme/theme.ts**

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {},
    typography: {},
    components: {},
    status: {
        danger: '#ee7403'
    }

});

export default theme;
```

**src/theme.d.ts**

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Theme {
      status: {
        danger: string;
      };
    }
    
    interface ThemeOptions {
      status?: {
        danger?: string;
      };
    }
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "index.d.ts", "theme.d.ts"]
}
```

Meanwhile if I move everything from theme.d.ts to theme.ts then everything works fine but I'd like to keep module augmentations in a serapate file. How to do that?